# Flutter FCM IOS silent(data only) notification not received

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using data notifications to update my app state, it's working perfectly on Android but I can't receive any data messages on IOS the onMessage listener is not even triggered.

I'm using these:

firebase_core: ^0.7.0

firebase_auth: ^0.20.1

firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.15

firebase_analytics: ^7.0.0

I'm using POSTMAN to test it and it works on Android with no problems but data only messages to IOS are just not received.

Notifications with notification field are working perfectly on foreground, background & terminated the problem is only with data only messages.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

**I was able to solve this problem using this json parameters.**

[image]

Comment: "content_available" : true, work for me thx.